# Android change actionBar icon menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i want to change 3 vertical dot icon in actionbar. can i change that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can change that icon :)

1) goto resource folder (res) in folder structure then goto

2) menu folder in which you will find your menu.xml / main.xml or your created menu file in which you will find your menus
like setting menu and so on..

3) open that menu file you will get code something like that

4)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/post_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

5) just change the icon from line

```
 android:icon="@drawable/post_icon"
```

insted of default icon you can keep your own one through this line

happy coding